# How to populate a Java Apache Arrow Field List of Structs?

Tags: java, apache-arrow

I have a data set which is mostly a 2D table, however one column (`Field`)
(called Attributes) contains a `List` of `Structs` in each cell. Each
`Struct` has three `Field`s: Attribute Tag, Attribute Type and Attribute
Value.

The definition of the Attributes `Field` is:

```java
/**
 * Attribute Tag - Two character tag.
 */
public static final Field ATTRIBUTE_TAG_FIELD =
        new Field("AttributeTag", FieldType.notNullable(new ArrowType.FixedSizeBinary(2)), null);


/**
 * Attribute Type - One character type.
 */
public static final Field ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_FIELD =
        new Field(
                "AttributeType",
                new FieldType(false,
                new ArrowType.FixedSizeBinary(1), null),
                null
        );

/**
 * String representation of the Attribute value.
 */
public static final Field ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_FIELD = new Field("AttributeValue", FieldType.notNullable(new ArrowType.Utf8()), null);

/**
 * The field is a nullable List of Structs each with an attribute tag,
type and value.
 */
public static final Field ATTRIBUTES_FIELD =
        new Field("Attributes", FieldType.nullable(new ArrowType.List()), List.of(
                new Field("Attribute", FieldType.nullable(new ArrowType.Struct()), List.of(
                        ATTRIBUTE_TAG_FIELD, ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_FIELD, ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_FIELD))));
```

I have this code that attempts to populate the Attributes from some
source data. Although this produces no errors when run, it doesn't
result in any values in the attributes vector.

```java
final ListVector attributes = (ListVector)
ATTRIBUTES_FIELD.createVector(allocator);

// this is the source of the attributes that I will populate into the
attributes vector
final List<SAMRecord.SAMTagAndValue> recordAttributes =
samRecord.getAttributes();

if (recordAttributes != null && recordAttributes.size() > 0 ) {
    final UnionListWriter listWriter = attributes.getWriter();
    listWriter.allocate();

    IntStream.range(0, recordAttributes.size()).forEachOrdered(attributeIndex -> {
        listWriter.setPosition(attributeIndex);
        listWriter.startList();

        // put the values of the attribute in the arrow struct
        final SAMRecord.SAMTagAndValue samTagAndValue recordAttributes.get(attributeIndex);

        // I think the problem is here. In a debugger this seems to create a new writer not related to my Vector??
        final BaseWriter.StructWriter structWriter = listWriter.struct("Attribute");
        structWriter.start();

        final byte[] tagBytes =
            samTagAndValue.tag.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        // todo find out the type from the value
        final byte[] typeBytes = "S".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        final byte[] valueBytes =
            samTagAndValue.value.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        ArrowBuf tempBuf = allocator.buffer(tagBytes.length);
        tempBuf.setBytes(0, tagBytes);
        structWriter.varChar("AttributeTag").writeVarChar(0, tagBytes.length, tempBuf);
        tempBuf.close();


        tempBuf = allocator.buffer(typeBytes.length);
        structWriter.varChar("AttributeType").writeVarChar(0, typeBytes.length, tempBuf);
        tempBuf.close();

        tempBuf = allocator.buffer(valueBytes.length);
        structWriter.varChar("AttributeValue").writeVarChar(0, valueBytes.length, tempBuf);
        tempBuf.close();

        structWriter.end();
    });

    listWriter.setValueCount(recordAttributes.size());
    listWriter.end();
}
```

Why doesn't this result in any values in the `attributes` `ListVector`? What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I eventually found involves placing the `UnionListWriter` and the `startList()`, `endList()` and `setRowCount()` calls in the appropriate place.

The general pattern is:

```java
try (
   BufferAllocator allocator = new RootAllocator(Long.MAX_VALUE);
   
   // create all your vectors and other closable ...

   final ListVector attributes = (ListVector) SamAlignmentSchema.ATTRIBUTES_FIELD.createVector(allocator);
   // create the writer for the list vector
   final UnionListWriter listWriter = attributes.getWriter();

   // create the vector schema root
   VectorSchemaRoot samRecordBatch = new VectorSchemaRoot(
       aligmentSchema.getFields(),
       List.of(
           // add vectors including the list vecto
           attributes
       )
   )
){
    //allocate the VectorSchemaRoot
    samRecordBatch.allocateNew();
    
    // for reach sam record (read)
    samReader.iterator().stream().forEach(samRecord -> {
        int index = samRecordBatch.getRowCount();
        System.out.println("index = " + index);

        // set the values of the primitive vectors using set or setSafe ...

        // write a list of attributes into the attrbutes field
        final List<SAMRecord.SAMTagAndValue> recordAttributes = samRecord.getAttributes();

        // start a new list at the current index
        listWriter.startList();
        listWriter.setPosition(index);

        if (recordAttributes != null) {
            // for each attribute
            IntStream.range(0, recordAttributes.size()).forEachOrdered(attributeIndex -> {

                // put the values of the attribute in the arrow struct
                final SAMRecord.SAMTagAndValue samTagAndValue = recordAttributes.get(attributeIndex);

                final BaseWriter.StructWriter structWriter = listWriter.struct();
                
                // start a struct to go into the list
                structWriter.start();

                final byte[] tagBytes = samTagAndValue.tag.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                final byte[] typeBytes = "S".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                final byte[] valueBytes = samTagAndValue.value.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

                ArrowBuf tempBuf = allocator.buffer(tagBytes.length);
                tempBuf.setBytes(0, tagBytes);
                structWriter.varChar("AttributeTag").writeVarChar(0, tagBytes.length, tempBuf);
                tempBuf.close();

                tempBuf = allocator.buffer(typeBytes.length);
                tempBuf.setBytes(0, typeBytes);
                structWriter.varChar("AttributeType").writeVarChar(0, typeBytes.length, tempBuf);
                tempBuf.close();

                tempBuf = allocator.buffer(valueBytes.length);
                tempBuf.setBytes(0, valueBytes);
                structWriter.varChar("AttributeValue").writeVarChar(0, valueBytes.length, tempBuf);
                tempBuf.close();

                //finished with this struct
                structWriter.end();
            });
        }
        index++;

        // finished writing the list of structs for this position
        listWriter.endList();

        listWriter.setValueCount(index);
        samRecordBatch.setRowCount(index);
});
```